# How come when I block a directory in robots.txt, its contents are still coming up?

Tags: robots.txt

This is what I've got in my `robots.txt`, placed in the base directory, of course:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /foo/
```

But then, in Google, I have no index of `/foo/`, but for some reason, I still have `/foo/foo.php` showing up as a link in Google.

How come? Did I write something incorrectly? Do I need to write something else?

Comment: great question. I never knew this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put `robots.txt` after your site went live, Google could already index files under `/foo/`.

You can remove already indexed files via [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en) - removal request.

[image: Removal Request]

Answer (score 0):

robots.txt does not prevent Google *to link* to your blocked pages. Google won't *index* your blocked pages (so it won't show the page title/description/snippet), but if it finds a link to any blocked page, it might still link it from their search results.

If you want to also forbid this linking, you could use the `meta` element with `robots` and `noindex`.